# Unable to create directory for deployment Tomcat error

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

I'm trying to deploy a simple Spring Boot REST service to Tomcat, but it does not seem to work.
There is already one working service running on the Tomcat. It is in the webapps folder. I've followed this multi-war-deploying tutorial: https://www.tecmint.com/run-deploy-multiple-web-applications-instances-tomcat-centos-ubuntu/

So now I have two folders in /var/lib/tomcat9/, webapps and webapps2. I have also configured two Services to the server.xml as in the tutorial. I think the server.xml config is ok.

Tomcat logs shows an error:

**Unable to create directory for deployment: [/etc/tomcat9/webapps2/localhost]**

That folder consists of Tomcats configuration files, such as server.xml. Why is Tomcat trying to create folder in that location? Shouldn't it create a folder inside the webapps2 with the same name as the war is?

Comment: Have you checked tomcat logs?

Comment: @Ivan yes there are only entries about the workingservlet

Comment: Can you try and deploy the workingservlet app in the service that is not working, so that you have 2 services with the same thing. If only one works, then you know what to fix.

Comment: **Because the other WAR service has a folder in which there are META-INF, WEB-INF and a web.xml in which at least the URL is defined (/ThisWARWorks)** yes second war file should also have these components

Comment: do those folders get generated automatically somehow or why does not any tutorials mention this?